# Change boolean value from parent component in child component Angular

Tags: angular

I have child component with boolean variable

```
class ChildComponent {
    editMode: boolean = false 

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.editMode) }
    }
}
```

How to change editMode value to true from parent component?

```
class ParentComponent {

    onClick() {
        this.router.navigate['child-component']
        //change here editMode value to true
    }
}
```

I should do it without access do html template. Only in component

Comment: use `Input()` Decorator if your child component is inside your parent. otherwise you can use route param. or Subject service.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use property binding in the HTML template, but since you say this is not what you want, you will have to go with another way.
My recommendation is to use a Service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EditService {

  editMode: boolean = false;
}
```

```
class ChildComponent implements OnInit  { 

  constructor(private editService: EditService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.editService.editMode);
  }
}
```

```
class ParentComponent {

  constructor(private editService: EditService){}

  onClick() {
    this.router.navigate['child-component'];

    this.editService.editMode = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ViewChild decorator in parent component as below,

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;

onClick() { 
   this.router.navigate['child-component'];
   //change here editMode value to true 
   this.childComponent.editMode = true;
}
```

Here, Parent component accesses the instance of child component using @ViewChild decorator and update its property.